# why video cards/GPU are not like CPUs in terms of installation into a computer?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

why GPUs, generally are in another electrical board (video card) and are not like CPUs to be installed in the motherboard?

Comment: They are physically different. But serious, what are you trying to ask?

Comment: @Irsu85 what u did not understand from my question?  i asked just for curiosity.   what u mean that they are physically different?

Comment: CPU's generally have slower RAM, so the memory controller allows for the RAM to be a few centimeters apart. GPU RAM controllers expect the data to be almost instantly availible and the RAM needs to be way closer for that to work (physically)

Comment: This question is off topic for this site. If you are asking this to help you decide between some hardware (maybe looking for something with a socketed GPU?) then it would be on topic to ask that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the consumer market, as in the average person building a home pc from parts acquired from newegg or amazon, yes it seems like GPU's are not like CPU's in terms of their installation into a computer - with the GPU being on a separate piece of hardware (the graphics card) that plugs into the motherboard via PCIe slot (and use to be an advanced graphics port (AGP) back in the day).

But a GPU is very much like a CPU, in terms of die form factor.  And there are direct motherboard installations.  The best example being the SXM2 form factor from Nvidia.  You won't find this in the consumer market, this is in the enterprise / corporate realm where you are looking at a rack mount style server that costs upward of $50,000.

Dell has a model C4140 for example that incorporates some number of SXM2 style Nvidia gpu's, V100 model and later.  I'm sure there are similar offerings from other big manufacturers like HP, Supermicro, and so on.

The gpu is however many mm in length and width, and dissipates N watts, and requires cooling, just like a cpu.  Whether it's on a separate piece of hardware with it's own heat sink and fan, and is modular and plugs into the mainboard via pcie slot... or is incorporated onto the mainboard and has a heat sink on top of it just like the cpu does and uses case fans for cooling, is just form factor and is trivial.

look at https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Enterprise/GPU-Server/G190-G30-rev-100

we get gpu incorporated in to the cpu currently, with Intel's integrated graphics for example, so you can have a motherboard that has vga/dvi/hdmi/dp ports on it and you're not required to install a dedicated graphics card to get graphics.  Will the consumer market ever see higher end gpu capability that **sort of** comes with on-motherboard gpu like the SXM form factor?  with just 1 gpu there's no real good reason to go SXM style over modular pcie graphics card.  SXM shines over pcie when you have multiple gpu's doing hard core gpu type of [cuda] processing, not just rendering graphics to a monitor to play a game.  but who knows.

Comment: will we ever see laptops with *on-motherboard* high end V100 type of gpgpu, whether it's 1 or 2, for on-the-go deep-learning gpu processing for that nutjob who has to keep working while on work travel while on the plane?   currently there's not a market for it, but who knows.  But i wouldn't be surprised to see available a $5000 workstation type of laptop having 1 gpgu having a mega Li-ion battery.  This was actually a pretty good question.

Comment: it's all just form factor - nvidia RTX 40 series laptops.

Comment: how bout that: nvidia - MSI Titan GT77 HX 13VI GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU, Intel Core i9-13980HX, 17.3", 128 GB DDR5, 4 TB NVMe SSD, $5299.